# How to convert a signal form time domain to frequency domain using python

Tags: matlab, python

I'm a newbie of DSP and I have some problems when trying to convert this signal:

```
signal= [ -0.0018225230, -0.0015879294, +0.0000000000, +0.0036977508, +0.0080754303, +0.0085302217, -0.0000000000, -0.0173976984, -0.0341458607, -0.0333591565, +0.0000000000, +0.0676308395, +0.1522061835, +0.2229246956, +0.2504960933, +0.2229246956, +0.1522061835, +0.0676308395, +0.0000000000, -0.0333591565, -0.0341458607, -0.0173976984, -0.0000000000, +0.0085302217, +0.0080754303, +0.0036977508, +0.0000000000, -0.0015879294, -0.0018225230 ]
```

I saw this code from the internet using matlab:

```
clear;
value = [42007935 111212895 184546560 238219725 238219725 184546560 111212895   42007935];
time = 0:7;
stem(time,value,'markerfacecolor',[0 0 1])
title('Time Data'); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('Amplitude');
 
dftvalue = fft(value);
freq = -pi:(2*pi)/length(value):pi-(2*pi)/length(value);
figure;
freq;
 
stem(freq,abs(fftshift(dftvalue)),'markerfacecolor',[0 0 1])
title('Magnitude of DFT'); xlabel('Frequency'); ylabel('Magnitude');
figure;
 
stem(freq,angle(fftshift(dftvalue)),'markerfacecolor',[0 0 1])
title('Phase of DFT');
xlabel('Frequency'); ylabel('Magnitude');
```

But I don't know how to convert this line from matlab to python:

```
freq = -pi:(2*pi)/length(value):pi-(2*pi)/length(value);
```

Comment: @MBaz here i have a signal like above. And i want to convert it into frequency domain and plot it .

Comment: MBaz is correct, the other question is identical and the answer is appropriate to your question. Please review and ask further questions there if not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi
freq = np.arange(-pi,pi,(2*pi)/len(value))
```

Comment: I using this code and plot the freq then I got a figure of a line. I dont think that correct.

Comment: My answer is regarding your question of how to convert the specific code line you mentioned from Matlab to Python. This gives you a "line" because it's a vector of frequencies. In order to see the signal you should combine it in the full code you showed here.